# Unexpected output for int type

Tags: java, int, size

Learning JAVA, i was trying to test the upper limit of `while` loop which goes on incrementing an `int`.Please see the program below :

```
 public class Test {

   public static int a(){
     int a = 10;
      while(a > 9 )
          ++a;
      return a; 
   }

   public static void main(String[] argc) {

         Test t = new Test();
         int k = t.a();
         System.out.println("k = "+(1 * k));    
    }
}
```

I am aware that 32 bits range is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, so on the basis of that, i was expecting output as `2,147,483,647` but instead i am getting :

```
k = -2147483648
```

I even tried

```
 System.out.println("k = "+(1 * k/2));
```

but still output is :

```
k = -1073741824
```

**Question :**

Why is solution negative when it should be positive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incrementing your `a` `int` by `1` until it reaches `1 + Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which shifts its value to `-2147483648 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Here's your loop commented:

```
// "infinite" loop as a is assigned value 10
while(a > 9)
    // when a reaches Integer.MAX_VALUE, it is still incremented by 1
    ++a;
// loop condition now false, as value for a has shifted to -2147483648
return a;
```

Comment: **question :** so when we cross the `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, we are automatically shifted to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`...is reverse also true?

Comment: @NoobEditor yes. `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE` as there is no explicit error for overflow nor underflow.

Comment: I wish I know this 2 years ago! I was bewildered. Thanks for a clear answer, +1

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is called [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Maximum 32-bit integer value in binary is:

`0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`

When you add 1 to this number you get:

`1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

This is the [twos compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), or -2,147,483,648. Since any negative number is less than 9, the while loop exits.

Answer (score 1):

### If we look at [Oracle docs on int values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) We can find out that:

***`The operators that work on the int primitive value do not indicate overflow or underflow`***

The results are specified by the **language** and **independent** of the **JVM** version as folows:

`Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` ***`is the same as`*** `Integer.MIN_VALUE`
`Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1` ***`is the same as`*** `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

You increment the value until it reaches the positive limit and it becomes all bits but the sign bit becomes 1.

> 0x7FFFFFFF = 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111

This is binary representation of 2147483647, which is INT_MAX. When you increment it by one once again, it becomes

> 0x80000000 = 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

which is equal to INT_MIN, -2147483648.

Now,

2147483647 is greater than 9 so your loop continues. One more increment and oops, suddenly it is -2147483648 which is smaller than 9. This is the point where your loop condition fails.